# Regex For accept alphapet and special charcter

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

For the below line

`ERROR: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/example/test@script/Jenkinsfile not found`

**Conditions:**

1.Have to start the line with `ERROR`

2.where **example/test** will change dynamically

How to achieve this through Regex

Comment: Hi @Kali. Post your attempts.. BTW I'm not the dv.

Comment: does the part "example/test" always contain a slash or can it be just one word?

Comment: @Marco It.s not a one word.its two word separate by slash

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
^ERROR: \/var\/lib\/jenkins\/workspace\/[\w+\/]*@script\/Jenkinsfile not found$
```

Explanation:

```
^                                          -- start of string
ERROR: \/var\/lib\/jenkins\/workspace\/    -- fixed portion of path
[\w+\/]+                                   -- variable portion
@script\/Jenkinsfile not found             -- fixed portion of path
$                                          -- end of string
```

The capture group `[\w+\/]+` captures variable strings like `example/test` `example` or `foo/bar/baz/staging`

[Regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/Jk7IIP/2)

Edit:
if the variable part is always 2 words seperated by a slash you can do something like this:

```
^ERROR: \/var\/lib\/jenkins\/workspace\/\w+\/\w+@script\/Jenkinsfile not found$
```

Here we are simply using `\w+\/\w+`, which means: Match any alphabetical character one or multiple times, followed by a slash followed by any word character one or multiple times